Using a struct inside a struct Stack. What is wrong?
I'm trying to use a struct inside a struct Stack. The Point struct stores two members, and I want to know how to reorganize this code without using a vector or pair.
typedef struct {
    // Array to store stack elements
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    // Index of the top element in the stack
    int top;

    struct Point {

        int x;
        int y;
    } point;


} Stack;

Does anyone know where to start?
I'm trying to create a set of pairs with a struct (x, y). I'm working on a maze algorithm. Trying to figure out how to set up this struct/struct stack to create ordered pairs for pushing and popping.

Your code doesn't use any std::vector or std::pair, what do you want to reorganise?

without using a vector or pair - why, is this a school assignment?  Not that it's clear to me at all what you're asking

I don't understand what you are asking for. Do you want arr to be an array of point instead of int?

I thought about making the arr an array of point, but it would have to have a pointer to both members.

Okay, now it makes less sense to me. shrug

"without using a vector or pair" - does that mean you also can't use std::stack, either? In any case, why is Point nested inside of Stack? It probably should be declared outside instead. "I thought about making the arr an array of point, but it would have to have a pointer to both members" - why? What is the actual goal here?

A stack is just a structure to store a list of some thing. It can be any thing.
Physically, I can stack a bunch of plates. Or papers. Or books. Or boxes, where each box holds two teddy bears.
Same in code. Each item in a stack can be a integer, or a string, or a Student or Employee or... a point. Hence, you can create a thing:
typedef
struct Point
{
    int x, y;
}
Point;

And you can create a stack that holds that kind of thing:
typedef
struct Stack
{
    Point arr[MAX_STACK_SIZE];
    int top; // -1 for empty stack
}
Stack;

Thereafter it is easy to create/initialize a stack:
void CreateStack( Stack * S )
{
    S.top = -1;
}

And push a point:
void Push( Stack * S, Point p )
{
    if (S.top + 1 < MAX_STACK_SIZE)
        S.arr[++S.top] = p;
}

etc. User code then becomes very easy:
int main(void)
{
    Stack my_stack;
    CreateStack( &my_stack );

    Point p = { 2, 3 };
    Push( &my_stack, p );

    ...

P.S. You can make a function to create a point, too:
Point CreatePoint( int x, int y )
{
    Point p = { x, y };
    return p;
}

And then use it:
    Push( &my_stack, CreatePoint( 5, 7 ) );

